# ZipFile cracker works with a few combinations and crashes when many combinations are used

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I've found many examples of zip crackers written in python, but unfortunatelly they were either written in python2 or have the functionality I do not need (i.e. use of dictionaries saved in files). For me was interesting to check how long and how much memory will it take to break, let's say, a password of 5-10 different symbols (a-z, a-zA-Z, a-zA-Z1-10 etc.). Afterwards I can try different libraries and techniques (threads etc.) to improve performance of the code and, hopefully, get better undestaning of python mechanics in the process.

Here is my program. It works well when the program tries 2-position passwords (a-zA-Z) and crashes with longer passwords.

```
import os
import shutil
import zipfile
from itertools import permutations, combinations_with_replacement
from string import ascii_letters

#passgen() yields passwords to be checked  
def passgen(passminlength, passmaxlength,searchdict):
    prevpwd = []
    for n in range(passminlength,passmaxlength):
        for p in combinations_with_replacement(searchdict,n):
            for k in permutations(p,n):
                pwd_tmp=''.join(k)
                if prevpwd != pwd_tmp: #without this check passgen() yields 
                    prevpwd = pwd_tmp  #recurring password combinations
                    yield pwd_tmp      #due to the logic behind permutations()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    zFile = zipfile.ZipFile("secret.zip", 'r') #encrypted file to crack
    pwd = None #password to find

    output_directory = os.path.curdir+"/unzip_tmp" #output tmpfolder for extracted files
    if not os.path.isdir(output_directory): #if it exists - delete, otherwise - create   
        os.makedirs('unzip_tmp')
    else:
        shutil.rmtree(output_directory)
        os.makedirs('unzip_tmp')

    searchdict = list(ascii_letters) #list with symbols for brute force: a-zA-Z 
    passminlength = 1
    passmaxlength = 3 #code works with passmaxlength=2, doesn't - with passmaxlength=3
    pwd_tmp = passgen(passminlength,passmaxlength,searchdict) #pwd_tmp is an iterator
    while True:
        try:
            tmp = next(pwd_tmp)
        except StopIteration: #iterator is empty-> quit while-loop
            break
        print("trying..:%s" % tmp)
        zFile.setpassword(bytes(tmp,'ascii'))
        try:
            zFile.extractall(output_directory)
            pwd = tmp
            break #password is found->quit while-loop 
        except RuntimeError: #checked password is wrong ->go again though while loop
            print("wrong password:%s" % tmp)   
    print("password is:%s" % pwd)
```

The program crashes with maxpasslength=3 on the row with "zFile.extractall(output_directory)". 
Error is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Experiments\Eclipse\Workspace\messingaroundpython\zipcracker.py", lin
e 48, in <module>
    zFile.extractall(output_directory)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 1240, in extractall
    self.extract(zipinfo, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 1228, in extract
    return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 1292, in _extract_member
    shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 67, in copyfileobj
    buf = fsrc.read(length)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 763, in read
    data = self._read1(n)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 839, in _read1
    data = self._decompressor.decompress(data, n)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back
```

I am stuck. Any idea what I could be missing?

**Update:** It seems to be a bug from zlib. I added an exeption catcher to ignore bad combinations:

```
except RuntimeError: #checked password is wrong ->go again though while loop
        print("wrong password:%s" % tmp)   
except Exception as err:
        print("zlib bug, wrong password?:%s" % tmp)
```

Now the program can process much longer passwords.

Comment: Looks like a bug in zlib, revealed because you're feeding it garbage from a bad password. Honestly, I'd just catch it in the existing except clause and call it a day.

Comment: @user3757614 Thank you. I was afraid it was a bag. I did as you recommend and the program can work with longer combinations now. I will dump those bad combinations into a file to check what is wrong with them (or zlib) later.